# return function as an object literal

Tags: javascript

In this exercise I can't figure out why if I return the function I get an error, while if I return the function as a literal object it works

(module.js not works)

```
module.exports = {eleva : allaSeconda()}

function allaSeconda(){
    
    function calcola(num){
        return num*num
    }

    return calcola
}
```

(module.js works)

```
module.exports = {eleva : allaSeconda()}

function allaSeconda(){
    
    function calcola(num){
        return num*num
    }

    return {calcola}
}
```

(index.js)

```
const {eleva} = require('./modulo')
console.log(eleva.calcola(9))
```

Comment: Consider that `return {calcola}` is the same as `return { calcola: calcola }` (ie `return { calcola: function(num) { return num * num } }`). Your first example is the equivalent of `module.exports = { eleva: function(num) { return num * num } }`; there is no `calcola` property so `eleva.calcola(9)` won't work. It should be `eleva(9)`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little bit convoluted, you can simply:

```js
// no need for parenthesis in the exports.
// you export a function that elevates
module.exports = {eleva : allaSeconda}

function allaSeconda(num){
  return num*num
}
```

Which could also be done totally inline:

```js
// no need for parenthesis in the exports.
// you export a function that elevates
module.exports = {
  eleva: function(num) {
    return num * num;
  }
}
```

And you call it simply like so:

```js
const {eleva} = require('./modulo')
console.log(eleva(9))
```

Please note that your first example works, if you call eleva directly.